# How can I run a login test for 100 users at the same time using Selenium, TestNG and Cucumber?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, cucumber

I am a newbie in Automation testing. I have a list of 100 users in a excel spreadsheet:

```
User1: userid1/password1
User2: userid2/password2
```

... and so on.

I need to create a script and make all 100 user login into the same application , at the same time, simultaneously. Now, will 100 ChromeDriver Browser sessions open on my machine at once?

How can i do it using TestNG or say Cucumber Scenario.

Can i use HTMLUnit Driver or headless browser?

Please share some insights. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! What's your purpose for testing 100 users? Is it checking performance/load? Performance testing is considered a worse practice in Selenium. How does testing 100 differ from testing 1-5 users? Can you apply boundary values and equivalence partitions/classes to your test cases to limit the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine will most likely not be able to handle 100 chrome browsers at the same time.  I would suggest saving your excel file in CSV format and using jmeter instead.  A simple testplan like this should be sufficient.

1. User defined variables = URL and server info
2. CSV Data Set Config = point at your CSV file
3. Thread Group = controls the number of threads
4. HTTP Request sampler = login request
5. JSR223 PostProcessor = used to write output results
6. View Results Tree = for debugging your script

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing this outline, but can you just give an example of JSR223 Post Processor script?

Comment: can you give me some example on how to add url, server info in user defined variables?

Comment: Hi, @Toastman, if i want to do some user action after login, without opening the browser instance, can that be done in jmeter? I am aware about the Webdriver sampler , but that will open 100 browser sessions on my machine.

Comment: Hi Matt, please check out this link for jmeter basics:   https://lobsterautomation.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/jmeter-tutorial-part-1/ (disclaimer --- this is my blog).  Unless you have a specific requirement to use the webdriver sampler, I wouldn't bother using it.

Comment: will go through the tutorial. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is designed to write Functional and Regression test. Your requirement is to do the Performance test. Go with JMeter as mentioned @ToastMan answer. on top of it you can refer this blog https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler to use the Selenium webdriver with JMeter if you are looking for selenium like UI while perform action in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.